# How to convert rows into columns in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to have a same row which will have two columns like

[image]

With below code I am trying to union all the counts from table and view in one CTE.
Then using that CTE, I want to use PIVOT to have desired output.

```
WITH CTE_COUNT
AS
(
    SELECT 'TABLE' AS SOURCE_TEST, COUNT (1) AS TABLE_COUNT FROM DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME AS TABLE_COUNT WHERE SUBSTRING (TABLE_COUNT.SNAPDATE,1,10) = SUBSTRING (GETDATE(),1,10)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'VIEW' AS SOURCE_TEST, COUNT (1) AS VIEW_COUNT FROM DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME  AS VIEW_COUNT
)
SELECT TABLE_COUNT, VIEW_COUNT
FROM  
(
  SELECT TABLE_COUNT, SOURCE_TEST 
  FROM CTE_COUNT
) AS TableToPivot 
PIVOT  
(  
  SUM(TABLE_COUNT)  
  FOR SOURCE_TEST IN (TABLE_COUNT)  
) AS PivotTable;
```

Is there way to achieve this in Snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot`.

here is a sample SQL and output.

```
select * from(
select count(*) cnt , 'table' cat from information_schema.tables union 
select count(*) cnt , 'view' cat from information_schema.views  ) 
    pivot(sum(cnt) for cat in ('table','view'))
      as p ;
```

[image]